# MongoDB - Permit User to Create but Not Update a Document

Tags: mongodb, permissions

How can I allow users to create documents in a MongoDB database, but not update them afterwards?

Comment: What are you referring to by "users"? Do you mean developers or the public? How exactly does one connect with the database right now?

Comment: For example i have 2 different webpages, in first i want to have full access to database and in second i want to allow only create documents, without update, remove.

Comment: Are your 2 webpages on separated servers and on separated websites?

Comment: Yes, and both are connecting to the same database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a user defined role that allows insert but not update and then assign that user to it. See the link below as a reference
[A User-Defined Role Specifies Privileges](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-roles-collection/#admin.system.roles.privileges)

```
    {
  _id: "myApp.appUser",
  role: "appUser",
  db: "myApp",
  privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "myApp" , collection: "" },
         actions: [ "find", "createCollection", "dbStats", "collStats" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "logs" },
         actions: [ "insert" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "data" },
         actions: [ "insert", "update", "remove", "compact" ] },
       { resource: { db: "myApp", collection: "system.js" },
         actions: [ "find" ] },
  ],
  roles: []
}
```

Comment: So from serverA i can use userA mongodb and from serverB i can use userB mongodb